# What are some of the most widely used fuzzers for solidity?

Tags: solidity, testing, foundry

I can't seem to find a good overview of the current state of Solidity fuzzers and don't know which ones might be considered old at the time of writing. I have been looking into [echidna](https://github.com/crytic/echidna) and [foundry](https://github.com/gakonst/foundry). The Solidity docs also mention **SMTChecker**. I would be grateful for any additional information/experiences with these libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr hevm, Echidna, Harvey, Foundry

I keep a list of formal verification tools, and recently separated tools by fuzzers as well: https://github.com/leonardoalt/ethereum_formal_verification_overview
(need to update with Foundry)

[SMTChecker](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/smtchecker.html) is a model checker based on Horn solvers, it overlaps with fuzzers in what it can achieve, but both have different and complementary pros and cons.

Comment: Amazing, thanks. Is there any that you'd personally recommend to someone starting out with formal verification?

Comment: In general (not only fuzzers or fv): Slither, Echidna, Act, hevm/dapptools, Foundry fuzzer, Scribble, SMTChecker. A few others are not open access.